# How do I run and external continually running C program with PHP?

Tags: php, c

I have code PHP code in my web app that runs an executable c program that I have. The c program constantly runs and outputs data to an output file.

I'm currently using this line to run the program

```
exec("/var/www/mcc-libhid/test-usb20X f &");
```

The problem is that since the program never ends, I get stuck on a loading page on my web app. I'd like my php code to start running this program and quickly return. Not wait for some end of it.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: Is the program flow dependent on the `exec(...)` command? That is, any `if` or `else` is related to that?

Comment: Just run in back ground

Comment: The program pulls data from the output file that the c program constantly appends to. The program checks the output file every 5 seconds for changes. I just need my start button to somehow launch the c program. Exec() seems to do the trick, but it waits for the c program to close before returning which stops the flow of my program because the c program will never close. It must keep running

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question!

Here is the updated line that did what I wanted.

```
exec("/var/www/mcc-libhid/test-usb20X f >/dev/null &");
```